# C++ manually Convert string to int?

Tags: c++

I was trying to manually convert a string to an int, and I have had difficulties. I first check to see if the string entered is an integer. Next, I want to convert that string to an integer without using any library methods.

When I ran the code inside my loop line by line, it did what I needed it to, but when I ran it inside a loop, it spat out incorrect binary results.

==> I am going to check if the value you enter is a number.

==> Enter a number: 234

==> Input result: 1

==> Press enter to continue...

==> 11001

```
// Darian Nwankwo, Random Programs, August 2, 2015

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string number = "";
    bool isNumber = false;

    std::cout << "I am going to check if the value you enter is a number." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cin.ignore();

    // Iterate through variable number to check if it is a number
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < number.length() ; i++ ) {
        if ( number[i] < 48 || number[i] > 57) {
            break;
        } else {
            isNumber = true;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Input result: " << isNumber << std::endl;

    int newNumber = 0;             
    // Iterates over the number string variable and converts value to an integer
    if (isNumber) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < number.length() ; i++ ) {
            // newNumber += std::pow( 10.0, number.length() )
            newNumber = std::pow(10.0, ( number.length() - ( i + 1 ) ) * ( number[i] - '0' ));
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Can't convert." << std::endl;
    }

    char cont;
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get(cont);
    std::cout << newNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first loop is wrong. Think what happens if input is `1a2`, what is Value of `isNumber` afrer the loop then?

Comment: Using `std::pow` here is redundant. You can do the whole thing with integer math only.

Comment: `pow` is a library method. It is also a total waste in this task. For some unfathomable reason everybody seems to use it and I for the life of me cannot understand why. If you have discovered that your digits so far are 13702 and the next digit is 9, you don't have to use library facilities to come up with 137029.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your for loop to:

```
    for ( int i = number.length() -1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
        int power = number.length() - i -1;
        newNumber += (std::pow( 10.0,  power) * (number[i] - '0'));
```

and make newNumber to double.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Wow, this worked and it seemed like the same thing I did, just starting from the last digit. What made this work and mine not? What was the major difference in our code? @Abhishek Mittal

Comment: Thats great :). Difference is in the for loop constraints.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what constraints I imposed on myself. Could you explicitly point them out please :)?

Comment: You missed the "+" in newNumber.

You have added "newNumber =" instead of "newNumber +="

Comment: It's a bad idea to use floating point arithmetic when trying to do exact integer calculation.

Comment: We can use unsigned long int, if needed to do big integer analysis.

Comment: @AbhishekMittal it's not that, but floating-point arithmetic is inherently inexact. You don't need to go through the string backwards, computing a power of ten upon every single iteration using `pow()`. You can just go forward, multiply the result so far by ten and add the next digit.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code:

```
    // Darian Nwankwo, Random Programs, August 2, 2015

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string number = "";
    bool isNumber = true;     // <-----should be default true

    std::cout << "I am going to check if the value you enter is a number." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cin.ignore();
    // Iterate through variable number to check if it is a number
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < number.length() ; i++ ) {
        if ( number[i] < 48 || number[i] > 57) {
            isNumber = false;       // <--- if not number, turn isNumber to be false
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Input result: " << isNumber << std::endl;

    int newNumber = 0;             
    // Iterates over the number string variable and converts value to an integer
    if (isNumber) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < number.length() ; i++ ) {
            // newNumber += std::pow( 10.0, number.length() )
            newNumber = newNumber + std::pow(10.0, ( number.length() - ( i + 1 ) )) * ( number[i] - '0' );   // <--- pow() should not include (number[i] - '0') and newNumber should be cumulative
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Can't convert." << std::endl;
    }

    char cont;
    std::cout << "Press enter to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get(cont);
    std::cout << newNumber;

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it can help.